# How to recursively copy entire directory including parent folder in Java

Tags: java, directory

I am currently coping folders from one place to another. It is working fine out but it is not copying the original folder that all the rest of the files and folders are in over as well. This is the code I am using:

```
public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
  if (src.isDirectory()) {
    //if directory not exists, create it
    if (!dest.exists()) {
      dest.mkdir();
    }
    //list all the directory contents
    String files[] = src.list();
    for (String file : files) {
      //construct the src and dest file structure
      File srcFile = new File(src, file);
      File destFile = new File(dest+"\\"+src.getName(), file);
      //recursive copy
      copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
    }
  } else {
    //if file, then copy it
    //Use bytes stream to support all file types
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest); 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    //copy the file content in bytes 
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
      out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
    System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);
  }
}
```

So I have the folder src `C:\test\mytest\..all folders..`

I want to copy it to `C:\test\myfiles`

But instead of getting `C:\test\myfiles\mytest\..all folders..` im getting `C:\test\myfiles\..all folders..`

Answer (score 11):

Try using the [copyDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html) method from the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library instead.

Comment: I have had a look at this but decided not to use it as I want full control over how the directories are copied so I can edit how they are copied easily

Comment: What do you mean by "how they are copied"?

Comment: and how do you add it to netbeans, i cant find the .jar file anywhere?

Comment: Here: http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi and here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4

Answer (score 4):

There is a [tutorial for copying files using java.nio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) with a recursive copy [example code on Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java). It works with java se 7+. It uses Files.walkFileTree method, which [might cause some issues on ntfs with junction points](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8069345). To avoid using Files.walkFileTree, the possible solution can look like:

```
public static void copyFileOrFolder(File source, File dest, CopyOption...  options) throws IOException {
    if (source.isDirectory())
        copyFolder(source, dest, options);
    else {
        ensureParentFolder(dest);
        copyFile(source, dest, options);
    }
}

private static void copyFolder(File source, File dest, CopyOption... options) throws IOException {
    if (!dest.exists())
        dest.mkdirs();
    File[] contents = source.listFiles();
    if (contents != null) {
        for (File f : contents) {
            File newFile = new File(dest.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + f.getName());
            if (f.isDirectory())
                copyFolder(f, newFile, options);
            else
                copyFile(f, newFile, options);
        }
    }
}

private static void copyFile(File source, File dest, CopyOption... options) throws IOException {
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath(), options);
}

private static void ensureParentFolder(File file) {
    File parent = file.getParentFile();
    if (parent != null && !parent.exists())
        parent.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've extended the answer.

Comment: You saved my day! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [Apache FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to copy directories as well

Answer (score 1):

You should try [apache commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 1):

Using java.nio:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public static void copy(String sourceDir, String targetDir) throws IOException {

    abstract class MyFileVisitor implements FileVisitor<Path> {
        boolean isFirst = true;
        Path ptr;
    }

    MyFileVisitor copyVisitor = new MyFileVisitor() {

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            // Move ptr forward
            if (!isFirst) {
                // .. but not for the first time since ptr is already in there
                Path target = ptr.resolve(dir.getName(dir.getNameCount() - 1));
                ptr = target;
            }
            Files.copy(dir, ptr, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
            isFirst = false;
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            Path target = ptr.resolve(file.getFileName());
            Files.copy(file, target, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            throw exc;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            Path target = ptr.getParent();
            // Move ptr backwards
            ptr = target;
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    };

    copyVisitor.ptr = Paths.get(targetDir);
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(sourceDir), copyVisitor);
}
```

Comment: Try to explain with some introduction where your answer does apply

Answer (score 1):

And of course **spring** has that covered also with [FileSystemUtils.copyRecursively(File src, File dest)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.0.RC2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FileSystemUtils.html#copyRecursively-java.io.File-java.io.File-)

Answer (score 1):

This Solution is very simple but is NOT platform independent since the command is given to the operating system in plain text. (This example is for Unix based shells, for Windows the command will look a little different `cp` is called `copy`).

```
String source = "/user/.../testDir";
String destination = "/Library/.../testDestination/testDir";
String command = "cp -r " + source + " " + destination;
Process p;
try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
    // Error handling
}
```

If you want the objects to be copied inside a subfolder with the same name, add it in the destination path, otherwise just omit it, then the folder content will be copied directly into the destination path.

Edit: just found out that unfortunately this solution does not work on Network drives. The reasons are unknown to me (but I admit I didn't dig for any reason)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is this:

```
  dest.mkdir();
```

only create one directory, not the parent one, and after the first step you need to create two directories, so replace `mkdir` with `mkdirs`.
After that I guess that you'll have duplicate child directories because of your recursion (something like C:\test\myfiles\mytest\dir1\dir1\subdir1\subdir1...), so also try to fix this lines:

```
    File destFile = new File(dest, src.getName());
    /**/
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, src.getName()));
```

Answer (score -1):

This code copies a folder from source to destination:

```
    public static void copyDirectory(String srcDir, String dstDir)
    {

        try {
            File src = new File(srcDir);
            String ds=new File(dstDir,src.getName()).toString();
            File dst = new File(ds);

            if (src.isDirectory()) {
                if (!dst.exists()) {
                    dst.mkdir();
                }

                String files[] = src.list();
                int filesLength = files.length;
                for (int i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                    String src1 = (new File(src, files[i]).toString());
                    String dst1 = dst.toString();
                    copyDirectory(src1, dst1);

                }
            } else {
                fileWriter(src, dst);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public static void fileWriter(File srcDir, File dstDir) throws IOException
{
        try {
            if (!srcDir.exists()) {
                System.out.println(srcDir + " doesnot exist");
                throw new IOException(srcDir + " doesnot exist");
            } else {
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcDir);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dstDir);
                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Revoke the second post:) already present some custom class for exception, i modified first post itself.. it's working fine!..