# how to get paths of files in given directory and files in subfolders?

Tags: java, directory, subdirectory

I have Fayl and Folder class which extends FSComponent abstract class which has add,setName and print methods. I want to print all files' path in given directory including files in subfolders. But in my main it only prints files and subfolder's pathes without including files of subfolders. How can I print files of subfolders too?

Abstract class

```
public abstract class FSComponent {

protected String name;

public void add(FSComponent c) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void print() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
}
```

Folder

```
 public class Folder extends FSComponent{
 ArrayList<FSComponent> list;

public Folder(String name) {
    list = new ArrayList<FSComponent>();
    this.name = name;
}

public void add(FSComponent c) {
    list.add(c);}
public void print() {
for (FSComponent c : list)
c.print();}}
```

File

```
public class Fayl extends FSComponent {
public Fayl(String name) {
    this.name = name;}
public void print() {
System.out.println("File: "+name);}}
```

Main

```
public class main2 {

static Folder main;
public static void listk(String path){
    File folder = new File(path);
     main=new Folder(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

            String path1=listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
            main.add(new Fayl(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath()));

          } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {

            main.add(new Folder(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath()));}  }}
public static void main(String[] args) {
listk("C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures");}}
```

Comment: Have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651900/how-to-recursively-copy-entire-directory-including-parent-folder-in-java  Copying file hiearchies is commonly a recursive application.

Comment: this works only if I don't add my files and subfolders to main Folder.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No it works but it doesn't show files of subfolders.

Comment: Please clarify this question by posting output or where in your code it is not working.  Thanks.