# Copy directory and everything inside it using Files API in Java

Tags: java, java-io

Browsing some answers I found that the following line should to the trick:

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(from), Paths.get(to),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

However, when I actually do provide some directory paths I get various exceptions or nothing is actually being copied, like for example:

```
kopiraj("C:/Users/Aleksije/Desktop/Rokovi/Rokovi 2016","C:/Users/Aleksije/Desktop/OVDE");
```

P.S. kopiraj(..) is a method in another class

```
  public void kopiraj(String from, String to) throws IOException {
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    Files.copy(Paths.get(from), Paths.get(to),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); //the line that matters
    proteklo = t1 - System.nanoTime();
    traverse(to);
  }
```

Comment: Can u please provide us the exceptions which are thrown?
U could also have a look at this answere : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651900/how-to-recursively-copy-entire-directory-including-parent-folder-in-java

Answer (score 0):

After some reading I found that:

> You can copy a file or directory by using the copy(Path, Path,
>   CopyOption...) method. The copy fails if the target file exists,
>   unless the REPLACE_EXISTING option is specified.
>
> Directories can be copied. However, files inside the directory are not
>   copied, so the new directory is empty even when the original directory
>   contains files.

Thus I had to modify my approach to work as follows:

```
  public void kopiraj(String from, String to) throws IOException {
    File[] sadrzaj = new File(from).listFiles();
    for(File f : sadrzaj) {
      if(f.isFile()) {
        sviFajlovi.add(f);
        Files.copy(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()), Paths.get(to + f.getName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
      } else {
        Files.copy(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()), Paths.get(to + f.getName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        kopiraj(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/", to + f.getName() + "/");
      }
    }
  }
```

To clarify for someone that might face the same issue:

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()), Paths.get(to + f.getName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

When using copy from one directory to another, it is a must to provide the new filename in the destination directory, that's why I added the name of the file that is being copied to the destination. (Otherwise you'll lose your destination folder).

```
kopiraj(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/", to + f.getName() + "/");
```

When copying the contents of some sub-directory you usually want to keep the contents in there, thus I call the `kopiraj()` method with a new destination, which has been updated to copy to the now copied sub-directory.